# Frustration in getting admission into PhD Computer Science, with background MSc Geospatial Science & BTech Computer Science

Tags: phd, graduate-school, graduate-admissions, computer-science

Am presently really frustrated in getting a supervisor and admission into PhD Computer Science in any University in Europe or US. I recently graduated with MSc Geospatial Science with distinction (cgpa 4.8/5) and I have Bachelors in Computer Science. Ever since I finished my masters have been seeking a PhD admission in computer science in any average schools in europe or US, but all to no avail. I have 3 research papers in top international journal, I even had a research proposal of likely topic relating to Mobile Computing & Mobile GIS, and i seriously think the frustration is weighing me down, please is there something am not doing right or there is any other method of getting a supervisor apart from contacting them through email.

Comment: Maybe you could describe in a few words how you have tried to get into PhD positions so far. What did your email contain?

Comment: The email contains information about my educational details, specialization and request to supervise my PhD research, and also my CV and likely research proposal.

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. You have told us about yourself, but you haven't told us about how you have been identifying potential supervisors and contacting them. Given the information you have provided, I don't see how we can answer the question.

Comment: Apply for a PhD in GeoSciences instead.

Comment: So you want to choose your own PhD subject…. But universities will only have funding in place for subjects they have chosen…..

Answer (score -2):

At all decent universities. Ph.D. admission is competitive. Apply following the official procedures to a dozen universities. Make sure your application file really is complete and on time at each. You will not be admitted based on contacting faculty informally.

Comment: This is true for US/Canadian/UK universities. PhD positions in continental Europe work very differently.

Comment: no this is not true for all US universities. While contacting a professor won't get you in, having a professor interested in you can help increase your chances if that professor informs the admissions committee to look out for your application. At some places this will help more than others.